# Implementing the relational algebra division operator in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, relational-division

Can some one guide in implementing the relational algebra division operator using sorting with syntactic support in postgresql?
Edit: This is to deal with the source code of postgresql. I need to add the division functionality in Postgresql.

Comment: You are expected to provide a lot more information. A test case, code example of what you tried (working or not), explain your use case. For now: we have a dedicated tag for `relational division` with quite a few questions & answers. Might give you some pointers. I added it to your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're meaning with sorting syntactic support, but the relational division operator seems like a mere convoluted join:

```
select a_.id
from (select a.id, array_agg(a.b_id) as b_ids from a group by a.id) as a_
join (select array_agg(b.id) as b_ids from b) as b_ on b_.b_ids <@ a_.b_ids
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29

---

```
denis=# create table a (id int, b_id int);
CREATE TABLE
denis=# create table b (id int);
CREATE TABLE
denis=# insert into a values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2);
INSERT 0 7
denis=# insert into b values (1), (2);

denis=# select a_.id from (select a.id, array_agg(a.b_id) as b_ids from a group by a.id) as a_ join (select array_agg(b.id) as b_ids from b) as b_ on b_.b_ids <@ a_.b_ids;
 id 
----
  1
  3
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not i want. I want to edit the source code of postgresql to add the division functionality.

Comment: @ashokarya2: by querying some meta information from the catalog, you could potentially wrap the above in an plpgSQL or C function. For a solution that wraps it neatly within the Postgres code base, methinks the correct venue would be the pg hackers mailing list.